# function st_contains(sde.st_geometry, sde.st_geometry) does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, gis, postgis

Please help, I tried using PostGIS `ST_Contains` function on Laravel

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function st_contains(sde.st_geometry, sde.st_geometry) does not exist
>
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

- Laravel Framework 6:13.1
- PostgreSQL 9.6.15
- PostGIS 2.4

[image]

This SQL query works fine if run in pgAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to qualify the function with the name of the schema that contains it: `sde.st_contains`

The explanation is that the schema is not on your `search_path`.

Comment: i execute "SHOW search_path" and the result is:

"$user", public, sde, etc..

Comment: Yes, but your program seems to have a different setting.

Comment: it's a fresh installed Laravel application, i'm wondering if there is config/setting to be modified first.

PS. I also tried converting the shape column to text (using ST_As_Text) and the POINT parameter is also in text format and it is working, the problem is that it takes a lot of time to execute the query.

Comment: Those seem unrelated problems, perhaps material for another question. You can change the default value of `search_path` with `ALTER DATABASE`. But why don't you add the schema to the function?